# You forgot to do, is it correct?

Tags: present-perfect

Someone has just finished cleaning the house, and I reply "No, you forgot to clean the entrance"

To me here between present perfect and past simple is still the difference between AE and BE, is it good?

I do not know, but in my point of view, if I say this sentence, it is easier to use past simple (for my brain :))

Answer (score 2):

This is correct in both British and American dialects.  There is a *tendency* for British speakers to use present perfect and a *tendency* for American speakers to use the past tense *in contexts in which both are possible*.  But it is no more than a tendency. It doesn't mean that using the past tense is an error in British English.

(The only mistake I can see is your use of "reply", since you aren't responding to something they have said.  So you aren't "replying".)

Comment: So even " I have forgotten..." Is correct. I should have used "say" or "tell" instead of "reply" because "reply" is not a transitive verb

Comment: You can use reply as a quotative verb  "She said, 'How are you?" I replied 'I'm fine'."  But you can't "reply" unless someone has first said something to you. . . "I have forgotten" is also correct English.